# Making a list of values from a loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, numbers, list-comprehension

I'm making a program as practice that would set a random number up to 400 for N, and a counter named K would be increased by one each time. At the end, I would like it to make a list of all of the values that were assigned to N.

Does anyone know how to do this?

```
import random
separateur = "============================================================"
def Compteur_bulletins():
  K = 0
  N = 36
  while N >= 36:
      N = random.randint(1,400)
      K += 1
  print("Nombre de bulletins au-dessus ou egal a 36: ", K)
  print("Valeure de 'N': ", N, "\n")
  print(separateur, "\n")
  return K, N

for x in range(10):
  Compteur_bulletins()
```

Comment: could you please elaborate more on what is the problem?

Comment: what do you mean will be increased each time? when will it finish to increase?

Comment: Basically the problem is that I'm trying to get a list of all of the ranodm values assigned to N in the while loop. K is just a counter, it increases by one each time N is greater than or equal to 36

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: Is your goal to generate random items between 36 and 400 if so why not use `random.randint(36,400)`

Comment: I just want to know how to find all the values that are assigned to N and add them together to get a total "N" value

Comment: Oh I see then why are you trying to return the value of K?

Comment: no, i just want a sum of all the N values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def compteur_bulletins():
    k = 0
    values_of_n = []
    n = random.randint(1, 400)
    while n >= 36:
        values_of_n.append(n)
        n = random.randint(1, 400)
        k += 1

    return values_of_n, k

values, count = compteur_bulletins()
print('K:', count)
print(values)
print('Sum:', sum(values))
```

Output:

```
K: 15
[193, 114, 203, 227, 328, 262, 133, 311, 211, 323, 86, 310, 226, 147, 223]
Sum: 3297
```

---

Or, if you want 10 different sums of the values of `n` as you have done in your code, you can do this:

```
for _ in range(10):
    values, count = compteur_bulletins()
    print(sum(values))
```

Output:

```
471
0
3243
1348
896
808
2865
867
0
2447
```

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to exclude the first value of N (36) and the final value of N (the one below 36), then something like this will work:

```
import random
separateur = "============================================================"
def Compteur_bulletins():
  K = 0
  N = 36
  valeures_N = []
  while N >= 36:
      if K >= 1:
          valeures_N.append(N)
      N = random.randint(1,400)
      K += 1
  print("Nombre de bulletins au-dessus ou egal a 36: ", K)
  print("Valeure de 'N': ", N, "\n")
  print("Valeures anciennes de 'N': ",valeures_N, "\n") 
  print("Somme:",sum(valeures_N))
  print(separateur, "\n")
  return K, N, valeures_N

for x in range(10):
  Compteur_bulletins()
```